# CALAYER apply background color plus pattern image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-animation, calayer

I am having fun with Core Animation stuffs.
I needed to apply a pattern image to a CALAyer.
That part work perfectly with something like that:

```
color = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "myPatternImage")! 
shapeLayer.fillColor = color.CGColor;
```

But now I need to apply a background color behind the pattern. my Patter image is a png (with alpha component). 
So I want to apply a simple Color to the shape and after apply the pattern Image.
Is there a way to do that on the fly?

Comment: I am animating those Layers. If I understand your comment, you mean that I can use a "clone" layer on top of my real Layer. But since I am animating my layers I will have to animating the clone Layer too; And it can become very complicated. So i prefer to use a solution based on sublayers.. But i didn't reach to make it works.

Comment: I said nothing about cloning layers. I said use two separate layers. The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another sublayer with background color and add it before your pattern background layer:

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
CALayer *solidBackgroundColorLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
solidBackgroundColorLayer.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.CGColor;
[[self layer] addSublayer:solidBackgroundColorLayer];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyPattern.png"]];
backgroundLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[backgroundLayer setBackgroundColor:[color CGColor]];
[[self layer] addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
```

Comment: Sorry I made an error in my question. I had put the bad code. I am not using the background color property but the fillColor property. Since my CALayers have uibezierPath inside. (I am using SVGKit).
So i tried something based on your answer:


    var solidBackgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: shapeLayer);
    solidBackgroundLayer.fillColor = color.CGColor;
        
    shapeLayer.addSublayer(solidBackgroundLayer);

but it didn't work

Comment: `fillColor` set fill color of the path in the shape layer, but you don't set `solidBackgroundLayer.path` with any path...

Comment: Ah thank you, I though that CAShapeLayer(layer: shapeLayer);  will copy all the properties from the shapeLayer to the new one, but it didn't copy the path.
Thank you very much now it works fine. But I am a little bit worry about the performance :)

Comment: @LastMove `initWithLayer:` is used to create shadow copies of layers, which is usually used during animations on presentationLayer. Calling this method to make a copy of your layer is utterly wrong. Create new layer and set path manually. All of this described in documentation which you should start reading btw.

Comment: Yes I understood that. btw I am not using this solution. Since I am making a lot of animations It causes FPS drop. Finally I combine a color and the UIImage to create a new UIImage that I can apply directly as a pattern. 
It give better performances.